# ajax loaded content vs normal content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, dom

what are the difference between the ajax loaded DOM , and existing DOM of a page,

is all the parts of a html page can be ajax loaded without any difference  compare to existing content,(like meta tag, script,styles etc)

what are the cases the ajax loaded javascript/content differs from normal loaded content?

Comment: Meta tags are read when the page loads. I do not think there are any meta tags that can be acted on after the page has loaded. The rest of the page (script, css and content) can be ajaxed. If you need event handlers bound to dynamically loaded content you need to delegate the event handlers

Comment: @mplungjan so ajax loaded content differs only by event handlers that too we can delegate the event handlers. so there is no difference between these two apart from event handlers

Answer (score 0):

from @mplungjan comments

The difference is,

1.meta tags are not reads after page load

2.event handlers

Comment: You have two accounts?

Comment: i am different from one above

Comment: manokarthick karthick is another person than  Mano Karthick - that is surprising yes

Comment: is it  wrong to have two accounts in stack overflow?

Comment: I thought it was since you can ask questions with one and answer with the other and build fake rep. But is seems to be allowed if you do not do such things: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260430/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-a-user-with-multiple-accounts-and-what-action-will
If you want to merge them, you can
http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts